# I have an install on blast and am using a local microbial database to run BLAST searches. "blastn" workd

Tags: blast

I have installed BLAST+ on my Linux machine along with a local copy of the microbial database. "blastn" works fine with queries like

```
blastn -query query.txt -db 16SMicrobial
```

However, blastp fails e.g.

```
blastp -query query_protein.txt -db 16SMicrobial
```

gives

> BLAST Database error: No alias or index file found for protein
>   database [16SMicrobial] in search path [..../databases]

My database directory has these files-

> 16SMicrobial.nhr  16SMicrobial.nnd  16SMicrobial.nog  16SMicrobial.nsi
>   16SMicrobial.nin  16SMicrobial.nni  16SMicrobial.nsd  16SMicrobial.nsq

My `.ncbirc` file has

```
[NCBI]
DATA=.../databases

[BLAST]
BLASTDB=.../databases
```

Any idea of what could be wrong please?

Comment: What is BLAST? This? --> http://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/

Comment: `strace` the execution of `blastp` and see if you can find the system call that errors immediately before the error message.

Comment: Yes this is ncbi blast. Except that I have a local install of this program which I am running.